# UNIX bash switch users back and forth

Tags: bash, unix, sudo

I'm testing if i can run the script as user1 then sudo as user2 to execute a section of the script as user, then revert back to user1 afterwards.

Apparently my script gets stuck after the first sudo and does not execute the succeeding lines. How can this be resolved?

Apologies as I'm really not experienced in shell scripting

```
#!/bin/bash
whoami
ls -lrt /myfolder
sudo -i -u user2
whoami

sftp ${othersvr} <<EOF
cd /tgtpath
lcd /myfolder
get -p *.txt
exit
EOF

sudo -i -u user1
whoami
ls -lrt /myfolder
```

Comment: you have to `exit` from each invocation of `sudo` (I'm pretty sure). Good luck.

Comment: still getting stuck with user2 after the first sudo. the command after the sudo to user2 doesnt get executed

Answer (score 1):

You should find a better way of doing what you want, like using [ACL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)s or something.

However, if you want to do it this way, take into account that `sudo` can receive a command

```
sudo -i -u user2 'whoami; ls -lrt /myfolder'
sudo -i -u user1 'whoami; ls -lrt /myfolder'
```

Comment: how can i properly do that if the command i want to be executed is an sftp. I have updated my example below for your reference

Comment: Just create a script doing all the steps you want to do (and to simplify escaping) and invoke it from `sudo -i -u user script`